# Dynamically create PHP object based on string

Tags: php, mysql, oop, casting

I would like to create an object in PHP based on a type defined by a string in a MySQL database. The database table has columns and sample data of:

```
 id | type | propertyVal
----+------+-------------
  1 | foo  | lorum
  2 | bar  | ipsum
```

...with PHP data types

```
class ParentClass {...}
class Foo extends ParentClass {private $id, $propertyVal; ...}
class Bar extends ParentClass {private $id, $propertyVal; ...} 
//...(more classes)...
```

Using only one query, I would like to SELECT a row by id and create an object of the type define the table's type column with other columns in the SELECTed row being assigned to the newly created object.

I was thinking that using:

1. `mysql_fetch_object()`
2. Reading the type attribute
3. Creating an object with type defined by type attribute

But know of no way to dynamically create a type based on a string. How does one do this?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

> But know of no way to dynamically create a type based on a string. How does one do this?

You can do it quite easily and naturally:

```
$type = 'myclass';

$instance = new $type;
```

If your query is returning an associative array, you can assign properties using similar syntax:

```
// build object
$type = $row['type'];
$instance = new $type;

// remove 'type' so we don't set $instance->type = 'foo' or 'bar'
unset($row['type']);  

// assign properties
foreach ($row as $property => $value) {
   $instance->$property = $value;
}
```

Comment: You can also pass arguments to the constructor
$instance = new $type(5, 'hi');

Comment: note that className must be a full-path, valid address of class, for example: ` $type = "app\models\MyClass"; `

Answer (score 10):

There's a very neat syntax you can use that I learned about a couple of months ago that does not rely on a temporary variable. Here's an example where I use a POST variable to load a specific class:

```
$eb = new ${!${''} = $_POST['entity'] . 'Binding'}();
```

In your specific case though, you would be able to solve it by using PDO. It has a fetch mode that allows the first column's value to be the class the row instantiates into.

```
$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE);
```

Comment: I don't get it, apparently you would get `$eb= new ${FALSE}();` or am I missing something??

Comment: The reason this hack works is because `${false}` evaluates to `${''}` (same thing as writing `(string)false`) and the variable with the name `[empty string]` is the one we just created in the inner bracket clause. Very nifty.

Comment: What is the name of this syntax? Where can I read more about it? Because I am not understanding it.

Answer (score 8):

```
$instance = new $classname; // i.e. $type in your case
```

Works very well...

Comment: But then how do you add the arguments of the constructor? Is it valid to do:

$instance = new $classname($parameterA, $parameterB);

Answer (score 2):

Below is what I was looking for when I came to this thread. use `{"objectName"}` (brackets) to declare or reference the object name in the form of a string.

```
$gameData = new stdClass();
$gameData->location = new stdClass();
$basementstring = "basement";

class tLocation {
    public $description;
}

$gameData->location->{'darkHouse'} = new tLocation;
$gameData->location->{"darkHouse"}->description = "You walkinto a dusty old house";


$gameData->location->{$basementstring} = new tLocation;
$gameData->location->{"basement"}->description = "its really damp down here.";

//var_dump($gameData); 
echo $gameData->location->basement->description;
```

This way of referring to the object seems to be interchangeable. I couldn't find the answer so i had to fool around with it Until I found a way.

Answer (score 0):

as silkfire says, this can be achieved by using PDO specific modes, so here is an example. Using your same database values and defined objects:

```
 id | type | propertyVal
----+------+-------------
  1 | foo  | lorum
  2 | bar  | ipsum

class ParentClass {...}
class Foo extends ParentClass {private $id, $propertyVal; ...}
class Bar extends ParentClass {private $id, $propertyVal; ...} 
//...(more classes)...
```

with a single query (you must name the field containing the class name first):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT type,id,propertyVal FROM table WHERE id=1');
$stmt->execute();
$foo = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE);
var_dump($foo); // $foo is a newly created object of class foo, with properties named like and containing the value of subsequent fields
```

this is cool but it gets cooler with a while

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT type,id,propertyVal FROM table');
$stmt->execute();
while ($object = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE))
 {var_dump($object);} // here all desired objects, dynamically constructed accordingly to the first column returned by the query
```

you can define a constructor (which will be called after the values from database are assigned to properties) to work on those dynamically assigned properties, say by replacing a string with it's uppercased value

```
class foo
 {function __construct ()
   {$this->uper = strtoupper($this->propertyVal);}}
```