# Can I instantiate an object from a concatenated class name?

Tags: php, class, object, instantiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically create PHP object based on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201335/dynamically-create-php-object-based-on-string)

Now and then I could save a line of code by instantiating an object from a concatenated string, e.g:

`<?php $_oMyObject = new "Path_To_My_".$_sClassName; ?>`

But this causes a parse error - is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: (I realize I could solve this using an object factory, but I was wondering if this can be achieved with special syntax.)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<?php $_oMyObject = new "Path_To_My_".$_sClassName(); ?>
```

Comment: Parse error. Question is already answered here: [Dynamically create PHP object based on string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201335/dynamically-create-php-object-based-on-string) (place in variable first) so we should close as duplicate.