# How to create a new object using a class-name stored in a variable?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of functions depending on a variable, I want to be able to do something like this:
*(It returns an error hence the problem I'm unable to solve)*

```
function($x) {
    fetch.$x.() // if x=Name I would like it to execute fetchName()...and so on 
}
```

and something like this

```
function($x) {
    $article = new \Cc\WebBundle\Entity\$X(); 
    // if x='name' to be executed Cc\WebBundle\Entity\name()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could do that:

```
$basename = "fetch";
$key = ...; // your logic for generating the rest of function's name

$functionName = $basename . $key;
$functionName(); // execute function
```

Now, the tricky part would be if functions contain arbitrary set of arguments. In that case you should use `call_user_func_array` ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)).

As for creating of objects, [meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201335/dynamically-create-php-object-based-on-string) explained here please clear how to achieve that.

P.S. This, in fact, has very little to do with `Symfony2`. This is a pure `PHP` question ;)

Comment: thanks . with trial and error worked perfectly saved me hundreds of line codes .

Ps:symfony2 ...that was just the context

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use the handy `call_user_func_array()` function like this:

```
<?php

$class = 'MyClassName';
$method = 'someMethod';
$parameters = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');

call_user_func_array(array($class, $method), $parameters);
```

I imagine you would need to escape back-slashes in any name-spaced class names though, i.e. `MCB\\MyClassName`.