# How to load a class by it's name stored in a variable

Tags: php

I have some classes each in a file with the same name as the class itself. I want to dynamically load the related file from a given name and return the class object, but I have only the file/class name stored in a variable. How's that possible?

```
public function loadClass($name) {
    include dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/' . $name . '.php';
    return $name;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically create PHP object based on string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201335/dynamically-create-php-object-based-on-string)

Comment: @TimCooper Does this work on static classes which I'm not going to instantiate them?

Comment: There is no way you can return a class in PHP.  The only options you have are to return a string of the class's name, or return an object (either an instance of the class itself or perhaps an instance of [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/reflectionclass))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
//test.php
class test {
    public function shout() {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }
}

//main file
function loadClass($name) {
    include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/' . $name . '.php');
    return new $name();
}

$class = loadClass('test');
$class->shout(); //prints Hello World!
```

For static approach, do this:

```
//test.php
class test {
    static function shout() {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }
}

//main file
function loadClass($name) {
    include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/' . $name . '.php');
    $name;
}

$class = loadClass('test');
$class::shout(); //prints Hello World!
```

Comment: My classes and their methods are static. Can you show me an example with static class? Does it differ to your version?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You can use [Autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

```
function __autoload($name) {       
   include dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/' . $name . '.php';
}
```

You can call you class as,

```
$obj  = new MyClass1();
```

Comment: I have a `switch($name)` which will load a file and a class based on the requested `$name`, where should I put this `__autoload()`?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($name) {
    $path = __DIR__ . '/classes/' . $name . '.php';
    if (is_file($path)) {
        require $path;
    }
});
```

- `__DIR__` is equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)`.
- You can define multiple autoload functions with **[spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)**.
- You should check file existence.

### Multiple Auto-Loading Example

Multiple functions are processed as **Queue**, not Stack.

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($name) {
    $path = __DIR__ . '/classes1/' . $name . '.php';
    if (is_file($path)) {
        require $path;
    }
});
spl_autoload_register(function ($name) {
    $path = __DIR__ . '/classes2/' . $name . '.php';
    if (is_file($path)) {
        require $path;
    }
});
$foo = new Foo('bar');
```

#### if `./classes1/Foo.php` exists...

1. `$path` will be `./classes1/Foo.php` in the first function.
2. `require $path` will be called.

#### if `./classes2/Foo.php` exists...

1. `$path` will be `./classes1/Foo.php` in the first function.
2. `require $path` will be skipped.
3. `$path` will be `./classes2/Foo.php` in the first function.
4. `require $path` will be called.

Comment: Can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate a new instance of the class with the `$name` variable:

```
public function loadClass($name)
{
    include dirname(__FILE__) . '/classes/' . $name . '.php';
    return new $name();
}
```

Comment: Does this work on static class which usually don't need any instantiation?

Comment: If it's a "static" class you can just call the static method in the class `$name::blablaMethod()`